# Formula for Transformation of Polynomial Coefficients under Rotation

Tags: rotations, transformation, legendre-polynomials

I have a function represented in a basis of 2D Legendre polynomials,
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^N c_n P_n(x,y)
$$
where $P_n(x,y)$ is a 2D Legendre polynomial given by
$$
P_n(x,y) = P_l(x)P_m(y)
$$
where $0\leq l \leq L$ and $0 \leq m \leq M$ and $n$ follows the sequence
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n & (l,m)\\ \hline
0 & (0,0)\\ 
1 & (0,1)\\ 
2 & (0,2) \\ 
\vdots & \vdots\\ 
 & (0,M)\\
 & (1,0)\\
\vdots & \vdots \\
N & (L,M)
\end{array}
$$
I want to know if there is a formula for how my set of coefficients change under a rotation applied to $(x,y)$? In other words, if $(x',y') = (x \cos(\phi) - y\sin(\phi),x \sin(\phi)+ y\cos(\phi))$, then my polynomial would now be
$$
g(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^N c_n P_n(x',y') = \sum_{n=1}^N c_{n}' P_{n}(x,y)
$$

Is there a convenient way to determine what my $c_n'$ values are?